# To create msword document through asp mvc 1.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ms-word

Hii 
   I am using asp.net MVC1.0. I want to create Ms word document through code I am using function :

public ActionResult GetPostOffline(string PostId)

```
{
    Post post = new Post();
    post = PostBLL.PostDetails(new Guid(PostId.Replace("'","")));
    string strBody =  post.Title +post.Body;
    string filename = post.Title + ".doc";
    Response.ContentType = "application/word";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    Response.Write(strBody);
    return View("~/Views/Posts/AllPosts.aspx");
}
```

It is correctly opening a word document but in that document it is not showing proper content . Instead of showing content it's is displaying HTML of my website.. What should i do .. please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
public ActionResult GetPostOffline(string postId)
{
    Post post = new Post();
    post = PostBLL.PostDetails(new Guid(PostId.Replace("'","")));
    string strBody =  post.Title + post.Body;
    string filename = post.Title + ".txt";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strBody), "text/plain");
}
```

I have modified the Content-Type from `application/word` to `text/plain` as what you have is a simple sting variable (`strBody`) and not an actual Word document. In order to create an MSWord document you will need some library.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a simpler solution. From your question, it looks like you want the file to open up in word, even if it is just plain text.  Here is my solution:

```
{
    Post post = new Post();
    post = PostBLL.PostDetails(new Guid(PostId.Replace("'","")));
    string strBody =  "<body>" + post.Title + System.Environment.NewLine + post.Body + "</body>";
    string filename = post.Title + ".doc";
    return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strBody), "application/word", filename);
}
```

I added the System.Environment.NewLine between the title and body. Not sure if it is necessary.

Comment: I have one more problem regarding it.. When i save file. the saved file shows html tags like<b> etc used while writing post can i remove them any how or they should not be in written format and actually bolding the text or some thing.. is there any way to do that

Comment: @user604610, I just found this out; it works great! Simply add the <body> tag around your text and you can add any html tag!  I edited my answer to show this.